# Error conectando a la base de datos con mysqli->real_connect()

Tags: php

Hola amigos cordial saludo. Tengo un problema conectando a la base de datos con el metodo de mysqli_connect. Este es el código:

De antemano agradezco sus respuestas.

```
public function db_connect($persistent = FALSE)
{
    // Do we have a socket path?
    if ($this->hostname[0] === '/')
    {
        $hostname = NULL;
        $port = NULL;
        $socket = $this->hostname;
    }
    else
    {
        $hostname = ($persistent === TRUE)
            ? 'p:'.$this->hostname : $this->hostname;
        $port = empty($this->port) ? NULL : $this->port;
        $socket = NULL;
    }
```

Y esta es la "consulta"

```
if ($this->_mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $port, $socket, $client_flags))
    {
```

Comment: Qué hace la función `_mysqli_real_connect()` y cuál es exactamente el problema? Hay mensaje de error? Cuál es?

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `real_connect` y no una [conexión normal con `new mysqli()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php)? ¿Entiendes **la diferencia entre ambas** [tal y como explica el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-connect.php)?

Comment: @Triby Este es el mensaje de error: Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'db_name'

Comment: @A.Cedano Debido a que estoy trabajando con sesiones, id´s y control de trafico, me exige usar ese método. Pero no me sale ese error :/

Comment: Al parecer estás enviando `db_name` en lugar del nombre de tu base de datos.

Comment: @Triby $this->bigdata el nombre está correcto, no entiendo porque no me funciona :/

Comment: Pero revisa [la documentación y los ejemplos de código del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-connect.php). Para usar `real_connect` **debes haber conectado primero sea con `mysqli_init`**. No veo que estés conectando previamente.

Comment: Lamento la confusión de mi parte, deberías leer la recomendación de @A.Cedano, porque para usar `mysqli_real_connect()` debes crear un objeto con `mysqli_init()` y luego conectar.